Woocommerce order products by discount percent %
I am try add a filter on woo commerce category view, to order products by discount percent.
I found and adding this nice code from internet, for function.php:
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'wcs_get_catalog_ordering_args' );
function wcs_get_catalog_ordering_args( $args ) {
    $orderby_value = isset( $_GET['orderby'] ) ? woocommerce_clean( $_GET['orderby'] ) : apply_filters( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby', get_option( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby' ) );
     
    if ( 'on_sale' == $orderby_value ) {
        $args['orderby'] = 'meta_value_num';
        $args['order'] = 'DESC';
        $args['meta_key'] = '_sale_price'; 
    }
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby_options', 'wcs_catalog_orderby' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 'wcs_catalog_orderby' );
function wcs_catalog_orderby( $sortby ) {
    $sortby['on_sale'] = 'Sort by on sale';
    return $sortby;
}

The code works, but not quite as I would like.
Products with discounts are displayed first, but by price, not by discount percentage.
Can we modify the above code to somehow calculate the discount percentage and change the product sorting?
I tried to modify the code, by my self, to calculate the discount percentage

You will need to create new post meta to store % value and change the sort to be this meta instead of sale price.

I was afraid of that

If we talk about 10-50 simple type products store sure you can loop and calculate % and sort it this way which still will be slower query. If we talk about 10000 variable products its a big no. In both cases i would go with custom meta. It's 5 min job saving server resources and issues in future. Alot of examples here how to add new meta.
